# Appstore EULA for particular country

Tags: ios, app-store, eula

When i try upload my application in appstore ,Rejected for the following reason

```
 Thank you for making the app available for us to review.
 It would now be appropriate to modify your app to restrict it to only those territories
 for which you hold a gambling license. 
 For information on location awareness options, please see the 
<a href="https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html">
 Location Awareness Programming Guide, available in the iOS Dev Center. 
 Please see 
 <a href="https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html">
 Monitoring Shape-Based Regions
```

I want to make application available only in UK and GERMANY, My Question is Should i want to edit EULA(end-user license agreement) added New EULA.Or any other Problem?Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: They are telling you that you need to add a geographical location check to your app to restrict it to being used only when in the countries that you have a gambling license. Someone from the US could download the app via the German app-store, and therefore gamble illegally within the US which could lead you to legal consequences (IANAL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the stores that your app appears in, log into iTunesConnect and click "Manage Your Apps." Select your app and click the "Rights and Pricing" button. You can select the stores you want from this page (UK and GERMANY). (If you see a line at the bottom that says "Unless you select specific stores...", your app is already for sale in all stores.)

All the Best.

Comment: I did and resubmitted last week with selected a specific countires, After the resubmission only they given the above description

Comment: Fazil: I believe , provide your own EULA,.

Comment: I will do it.Thank You :)